# Error when pip installing mysql: c1.exe

Tags: python, mysql, visual-studio-2015, pip

I'm on Windows 10 and I've been trying to pip install mysql, but keep getting the error message:

```
error: command 'c1.exe' failed: No such file or directory
```

I have Microsoft VC 14 installed, at C:\Program Files (x86)\
For some reason when I installed python, it installed at C:\Users\name\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36

I've tried moving c1.exe into the python folder, but that didn't help.
Do I need to move the python folder somewhere else? Will that mess up python in any way? Is there an easier fix?

**UPDATE:** I changed the PATH variable, and it resolved this error. Then it moved on to a new error:

I changed the path, and it resolved the error. Then I got a new error, related to the execution of c1.exe it seems:

```
_mysql.c
_mysql.c(42): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'config-win.h': No such file or directory
error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\\VC\\bin\\x86_amd64\\c1.exe' failed with exit status 2`
```

Comment: Why are you using pip to install MySQL?

Answer (score 0):

you might have to add a python path variable or change it. see config noted here: [How to add to the pythonpath in windows 7?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3701646/how-to-add-to-the-pythonpath-in-windows-7)

Comment: I changed the PATH variable and it resolved that error. Then a new error with c1.exe came up. See the edited OP.

Comment: I don't know that you can install MySQL with pip. I would install MySQL the regular way & then call it into your python script with a library for it (e.g. MySQLdb library or SQLalchemy)